# How to use .trace on a boolean variable?

Tags: python, tkinter, boolean, trace

I would like to know if there is some way I could use .trace method on a boolean variable.

If I try for example `bool.trace('w', function)` with "bool" being a boolean variable, it returns the error `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'trace'`.

The reason why I am asking this is because I need to run a function every time this boolean variable changes, and that's what I'm using with integer variables, but if you know an other way to do this, that would be cool too.

Comment: Oh no, that was a mistake ! I'm using it when using .get() on a control variable of a tkinter widget

Comment: You should be able to trace tkinter `BooleanVar` instances just like any of its other Variable classes. See [The Variable Classes (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm).

Comment: If you really use `bool` as the variable name, you should not get the error.  However, you should not use built-in class `bool` as variable name.